# Improper integrals where both limits are infinite

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

For an improper integral of the form $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \, dx,$$

I'm told that I must set $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \, dx =\lim_{c \to \infty} \int_k^cf(x) \, dx+\lim_{c \to -\infty}\int_c^kf(x) \, dx.$$

Why can I not set $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \, dx =\lim_{a\to \infty}\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx \, ?$$

Comment: I think that this can be set

Comment: Because that would be a principal value integral, not an improper integral ;)

Comment: I mean you could... depends on what sorts of properties you want. With the latter definition, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\textrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^a f(x)\textrm{d}x+\int_a^b f(x)\textrm{d}x+\int_b^{\infty} f(x)\textrm{d}x$ might fail (in the sense that it could happen that neither of the improper integrals on the right hand side converges).

Comment: More to the point, the existence of an improper integral shall attest that the integrand is overall "well-behaved". If you consider only symmetric ranges, $f$ can behave more or less arbitrarily badly, as long as that bad behaviour is symmetric so that the effects cancel, and the limit still exists. To avoid that, we let the upper and lower bounds tend to $\infty$ and $-\infty$ independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the definition is:

It could happen that
$$
\lim_{a\to \infty}\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx
\tag1$$
exists but one or both of
$$
\lim_{c \to \infty} \int_k^cf(x)\; dx,\qquad\lim_{c \to -\infty}\int_c^kf(x) \, dx.
\tag2$$
do not exist.

The situation where both of $(2)$ exist is called "convergence" of the improper integral.  The situation where $(1)$ exists is called the "principal value" of the integral.  The limit in $(1)$ may sometimes be written
$$
\text{P.V. }\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\;dx .
$$

The principal value can have bad properties that a convergent integral cannot.

---

**examples**

$$
\text{P.V. }\int_{-\infty}^\infty x \; dx = 0
$$
change variables $y=x+1$ to get
$$
\text{P.V. }\int_{-\infty}^\infty (y+1) \; dy = \infty
$$